# SQL Error Message: Find and Replace for Date Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, error, find

[image: ArcMap Operating System]

I am attempting to use the find and replace function within the Attribute Table Options to replace fields that contain dates in the following format: month/day/year (e.g. 03/14/2014). The field's properties type is DATE.

However, when I try to do this, I receive the following error message: Search Error, an invalid SQL statement was used.

I realize you can set up a field calculator expression to find and replace DATE strings but is it possible to do this within the Attribute Table Options Find and Replace or does the special character “/” in the DATE field preclude this?
See image for ArcGIS  version.

Comment: Honestly, I've never had much luck using the find/replace in the attribute table. I'd recommend using the field calculator, or better yet a python script.

Comment: Could you share what do you enter in the Find/Replace window in ArcMap?